# How to remove starch from silicone ("Oogoo")?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, hydrolysis, carbon-family, organosilicon-compounds

*Oogoo* is an easy and cheap way of creating silicone rubber objects from a hand-formable putty. Basically: just mix silicone caulk with starch (I'm using acetate moisture absorbing silicone caulking and corn starch), the silicone in the mixture sets in about 10 minutes. Links (there are also some relevant videos on Youtube on the TKOR channel):

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-Your-Own-Sugru-Substitute/

http://www.instructables.com/id/7-Things-To-Fix-Or-Do-With-Oogoo/

http://www.instructables.com/id/Oogoo-mixer-on-the-cheap-avoid-messy-hands-/

I'm assuming that the starch doesn't chemically react with anything in the Oogoo mixture, so I was thinking that it may be interesting to try and remove it from the silicone rubber. I imagine this could create a light-weight, porous silicone rubber.

What method could I use for removing the starch without degrading the silicone?

I was thinking maybe hydrochloric acid could hydrolyse the starch? I think it wouldn't harm the rubber? Assuming that could work, what concentration of acid should I use at what temperature? If I used 33% hydrochloric acid, should I dilute it first, and what would be the temperature for the hydrolysis of starch?

Comment: 33% HCl is pretty aggressive stuff. How about filling the caulk with something more soluble to begin with, like superfine sugar or NaCl? Maybe even grind the sugar or salt up finer yourself with a mortar and pestle?

Comment: I'll try using sugar or salt instead of starch and see how it goes. Possibly I should mix either sugar or salt with a small amount of water, to make the caulking cure fast. However I don't know how will this work.

Comment: Magnesium sulfate (Epsom Salt) is available as a heptahydrate. It can be powdered easily, and might provide the H2O. Or MgCl2.6H2O (winter deicing salt).

Comment: @JamesGaidis very interesting, thanks.